# Launch Kivy applications on RPi in framebuffer mode

Tags: python

I've been trying to make Kivy work on my RPi. I was told kivy files cannot be launched over SSH and hence I get x-window errors. I've tried launching the main.py of my test application in VNC, with the python editor and it didn't launch. What am I doing wrong? How can I launch a simple Kivy application?